# How to print range of lines after keyword Java

Tags: java

### Let me rephrase my question.I'm searching in file for some keyword.When i fond it,i need to print some lines preceding this keyword including it.

I want to print range of lines start with some keyword

```
line1
line2
someword
line4
line5
```

After i find this keyword i need to print line1 line2 and this keyword.
Any idea?

Comment: could you give a concrete example of your input and output?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show us some code and we can help guide you from there.  You may also want to rephrase your question.  You say you want to print some lines starting with a keyword, but your example states that you want to print lines preceding and including your keyword.  Which is it?

Comment: Do you want to print the lines located before or after the keyword ? Do you want to print the keyword before or after the lines ?

Comment: Sorry,updated my question

Comment: i don't get it. what exactly are you asking?

Comment: You lines are in file, in some ata structure like list or you read it from console? Or get it other way?

Comment: Sorry,cant past my code here normaly,Starf got me.I search in file for some keyword.After that i need to print range of lines above this keyword

Comment: So the print range ends with some key word? @IlgarMamedov

Comment: Yes.i check the file for this keyword,than i have to print preceding lines.@StefanSprenger

Comment: Have you tried `grep`?  `grep -C2 someword yourfile` will print exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I get this printout from console app based on Windows,so it hasn't `grep` by default...(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the question. Take in line-separated input, search line-by-line for a keyword. If the keyword is found, print the preceding n-lines, followed by the keyword.

```
final String input = "line1\nline2\nsomeword\nline4\nline5";

int numberOfLinesToDisplay = 2;
String keyword = "someword";

// Split on the newline character
String[] lines = input.split("\n");

// Loop over each line
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    String line = lines[i];

    // Checking for the keyword...
    if (keyword.equals(line)) {

        // Reverse the for loop to print "forwards"
        for (int j = numberOfLinesToDisplay; j >= 0; j--) {
            // Make sure there is something there
            if (i - j >= 0) {
                // Simply print it
                System.out.println(lines[i - j]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but this works for the situation described.

Edit: To read from a file, assuming performance is not a pressing issue, you could use some thing like this: (Untested!)

```
String keyword = "someword";
int numberOfLinesToDisplay = 2;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));

int i = 0;

// Loop over each line
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    // Add the line to the list
    list.add(line);

    // Checking for the keyword...
    if (keyword.equals(line.trim())) {

        // Reverse the for loop to print "forwards"
        for (int j = numberOfLinesToDisplay; j >= 0; j--) {
            // Make sure there is something there
            if (i - j >= 0) {
                // Simply print it
                System.out.println(list.get(i - j));
            }
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

Edit2: Added `trim()` to remove extra whitespace.

Comment: Your solution works)now i need to include it in my code

Comment: Need to work on your second example...cant get result from it...@starf

Answer (score 0):

I just updated previous example created by @starf and its work.I add "indexof" elemet to find my string.Thanks a lot for your help!

```
 try {
       String keyword = "!!!";
       int numberOfLinesToDisplay = 8;

       ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\some.log"));

       int i = 0;

       // Loop over each line
       String line;

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

           // Add the line to the list
           list.add(line);

           // Checking for the keyword...
           int indexfound = line.indexOf(keyword);

           // If greater than -1, means we found the word
           if (indexfound > -1) {

               // Reverse the for loop to print "forwards"
               for (int j = numberOfLinesToDisplay; j >= 0; j--) {
                   // Make sure there is something there
                   if (i - j >= 0) {
                       // Simply print it
                       System.out.println(list.get(i - j));
                   }
               }
           }

           i++;
       }



   }catch (IOException ie){
       System.out.println("File not found");
   }
```

Comment: The `indexOf()` method checks that the line _contains_ the keyword, not that they are the same. In your case "myKeyword!!!" would match "!!!". It may be that you have extra whitespace after reading from file.

Comment: Its output from some server,that indicate some problem during loading data in it.It always contain "!!!" symbol before error,that's why i use `indexOf()` method@starf

Comment: Aha, I see. In that case, you could use `.contains()`.